# Get the value by Document ID

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone let me know what issue is there in the below code.
Basically, whatever I write in the text box, "Hello Manu" should get changed.
Is this possible?

We can write this in Jquery. But I wanted to see if we can execute it without Jquery

```
<h1>Change the HTML content</h1>
<h2 id="hcontent">Hello Manu</h2> 
<input id='x' type="text" value = searchURL()></input>
<script>       
function searchURL() {
     document.getElementById("hcontent").innerHTML=x
}
</script>
```

Comment: `x.value` is how you get the content of the `<input>` element.

Comment: also you'd use `oninput` not `value` to attach the event handler